# Is $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ continuous at $x=0$? Whats the value at $x=0$?

Tags: limits, continuity

Is $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ at $x = 0$  continuous?
 Whats the value at $x=0~?$

Comment: I believe You do know about something Called L'hospital Rule?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Why can't you use Hospital? This CAN be approached with Hospital

Comment: This might be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092824/confusion-around-lim-x-to-0-frac-sin-xx-sin-x-x-sin-0-0

Comment: @DMH16 L'Hopital assumes you know the derivatives of the top and bottom. However, proving that $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \cos(x)$ usually USES the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ and so the logic is circular. depends on how you define the sine function though. Defining it in terms of power functions let's you do this.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That is true, however, it wouldn't be wrong to state that the OP can use Hospital to evaluate the limit (if he has been properly introduced to it). You clearly stated that "it doesn't work here", which is incorrect

Comment: @DMH16 It is absolutely wrong unless he can justify his logic. Does L'Hopital apply here? Yes. Is applying it circular logic without some proof of $\frac{d}{dx} \sin x = \cos x$? Absolutely. Therefore, using L'Hopital here might give you the right answer because the conditions are valid, but this is not a proof - it is circular logic.

Comment: @DMH16 If you are taking a heuristic approach or simply accepting that we know the derivative of $\sin(x)$ then I suppose you can use L'Hopital, but this isn't a very rigorous approach.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Generally Hospital's rule is introduced with differentiation, therefore, I assumed it would be correct applying the definition of such rule to this case. If the OP hasn't been introduced to differentiation then the geometric proof should be looked at. However, I insist in underlining that saying "Hospital rule here doesn't work" is a false statement.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't if you don't define its value at $0$ to be $1$. As it is written, the function $f$, defined by $f(x) = (\sin x)/x$, is not defined at $0$, so it is not continuous at $0$.

However, the function $g$, defined by
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\sin x}{x} &\text{if $x \neq 0$,}\\[1ex]
1 &\text{if $x = 0$,}
\end{cases}
$$
*is continuous* at $0$. Why? Well, this requires you to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} (\sin x)/x = 1$, which I will omit discussing (you can use L'Hospital's rule to handle it, although most calculus textbooks prove it using a geometric argument, since L'Hospital's rule is unavailable at that time to the reader).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^{2k+1} \over (2k+1) }$, so
for $x \neq 0$, we have
${\sin x \over x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^{2k} \over (2k+1) }$, and
since $\sigma(x)  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^{2k} \over (2k+1) }$ is analytic everywhere, we see that $\lim_{x \to 0} {\sin x \over x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \sigma(x) = \sigma(0) = 1$.

The function $\sigma$ is also known as $\operatorname{sinc}$.